# What is the difference between Truffle and Remix?

Tags: truffle, remix

Please list the differences between Truffle and Remix.

Where is the use of both applicable? Can somebody list this using an example?

Comment: there is a question: What is Truffle ? Change your question into what is Remix?

Answer (score 10):

Truffle is a development environment/framework for smart contracts, and Remix is an IDE in the browser.

They both provide the ability to test and deploy contracts, but truffle can be included in projects as a build dependency, whereas remix contains an editor.

I use truffle when building javascript projects based on smart contracts (e.g. Dapps), and use remix for its debugging tools.

### Source material

From the truffle [docs](http://truffleframework.com/docs/):

> Truffle is a world class development environment, testing framework
>   and asset pipeline for Ethereum, aiming to make life as an Ethereum
>   developer easier.

From the remix [docs](https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> Remix is an IDE for the smart contract programming language Solidity and has an integrated debugger and testing environment.

Comment: Is it possible to use Remix to call or debug contracts created by Truffle? My contract works fine within Remix, but not from my Dapp via Truffle, and I can't tell what's different.

Answer (score 0):

I basically use remix for testing out my solidity code after writing them. I make sure all the functions are working as expected.
I then move the sol file to my Vscode and use truffle to continue with the deployment of the code to the main net or the test nets